# Is address title field important in shipping address?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design, user-preferences

I am working on address book feature on ecommerece site. This feature lets user select shipping address from his previously saved addresses from a address book page. Is it important to have a seperate address title for each address? Example: Home India, Office New York, Shop Thialand etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the alternatives.  I've seen several common approaches.

1. You support only one stored shipping address per user, but they can overtype it with a different address.  In this case there is no need to enter a name for it.
2. You support two stored shipping addresses per user, a default and an "other".  If they want to ship to a location other than those two choices, they have to overtype it.  Again, you do not need to have the user enter a name for either address.
3. You support multiple shipping addresses per user, but do not provide the user a way to enter a name for the address.  This will require you to somehow list all addresses the user has set up, and let the user select the correct one.  That would work if there is a finite and manageable limit to the number of addresses the user may have saved, but if a user could have a thousand addresses, it might get awkward to navigate the list.
4. You support multiple shipping addresses, and you provide a radio-button of pre-created tags for the address:  "(X) home", "( ) work", "( ) other".  Assuming this is a customer-facing site, you might pre-select "home" for their first address, "work" (or the other unused category) for the second address they enter, and "other" for additional addresses.  When you present the list during shipping, you could identify each in a dropdown list by appending a prominent required field in the address, such as recipient name or street address line 1.  But the results might be awkward, such as "Home - G Munishwar", "Work - Care of loading dock 1", "Other - 1234 MG Ring Road", etc.
5. You support multiple shipping addresses, and you require the user to enter a name for each.  Keep in mind this would be extra work for everyone with a single address, and may be confusing for users who wouldn't understand why they would need to give a "name" to an address.  If this is a public facing site, I would suspect the majority of people have only a single shipping address, so this choice would be reducing the usability for most of your clients.

And of course there are likely many other ways to deal with this.  I've just listed some common ones I've seen.

Comment: very nice. I like your answer :)

Answer (score -2):

B - 201, Sitaram Smruti Building,

2 Floor,  Dr . Nemade Galli,

Telkosawadi, Dombivli West Thane,

Maharashtra, 421202

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your answer for completeness? Usually answers without context or explanation can be interpreted in more than one way. Thanks.